# Login gmail open message check for sucess or fail in message

Tags: java, selenium, gmail

> > Java Selenium program  Login to Gmail account in search box check for
> >     text this is working fine.  How to check if the message is a success or fail If I write a separate class im getting session ID null
> >     exception.

//  [image: SAP to Magento stock sync]

```
    WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search mail']"));
    Thread.sleep(100);
    searchbox.click();
    searchbox.sendKeys("SAP to Magento stock sync");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    searchbox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(1000); 
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions
        .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("xY a4W")));
WebElement NumberofRecord = driver.findElement(By.className("xY a4W"));
System.out.println(NumberofRecord.getText());
```

error:

```
TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.className: xY a4W (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:81)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// extract notification subjects
ArrayList<WebElement> notificationsSubjects = ...// code to locate displayed subjects
// resolve subjects
for (WebElement element: notificationsSubjects) {
 if (element.getText().split(": SAP")[0] == "SUCCESS") {
// do something
}
else if (element.getText().split(": SAP")[0] == "ERROR") {
// do something else
}
else {
System.out.print("Unexpected subject.");
}
```